# play.data.Form.Field to play.data.Form[models.xxxx] Is it possible?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working in a web application using PlayFramwork and Java.
I'm trying to implement a simple form in a main view but in this view I'm adding differents templates. I'm having some problems when I'm passing a parameter to a view.
The error is:

> type mismatch; found : play.data.Form.Field required: play.data.Form[models.Document]

Let me explain with the code.

Content of showUserView.scala.html / the main view

```
@(user: Form[User])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("Test") {

<H1>SHOW USER</H1>


    @newUserView(user)

    @documentView(user("document"))

}
```

The problem is in this line:

`@documentView(user("document"))`

Content of newUserView.scala.html / this is working ok

```
@(user: Form[User])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._


<H2>User's Form</H2>

@inputText(
    user("name"), 
    '_label -> "Name: "
)
```

Content of documentView.scala.html / this is the problem...

```
@(doc: Form[Document])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._


<H2>Document's Form</H2>

    @inputText(
        doc("number"), 
        '_label -> "Number: "
    )
```

I'm preparing the view to receive a Form no a Field... I don't want to change the parameter's type. I would keep the original template.

Any idea about that? how can I convert the Field parameter to Form[Document]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the form parameter to Field parameter in consequence the document view:

```
@(document : Field)

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._


<H2>Document type view!</H2>


@inputText(
   document("number"), 
   '_label -> "Number:"
)
```

Content of showUserView.scala.html / the main view

```
@(user: Form[User])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("Test") {

<H1>SHOW USER</H1>


@newUserView(user)

@documentView(user("user.document"))

}
```

In the controller I'm building the form:

```
Form<User> userForm = form("user", User.class);
```

It's a good approach for me, I care the model and decoupling from other views.

Answer (score 1):

You would need create and fill both models in the controller and then pass to your main view (`showUserView.scala.html`) separately:

```
@(userForm: Form[User], documentForm: Form[Document])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("Test") {
    <H1>SHOW USER</H1>
    @newUserView(userForm)
    @documentView(documentForm)
}
```

#### Anyway...

as I understood you want to edit some `Document's` fields in context of filled `User` in such case you should use only one Form (User) for both sub views and then in your action saving/updating the data find related Document by hidden id:

```
@(userForm: Form[User])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("Test") {
    <H1>SHOW USER</H1>
    @newUserView(userForm)
    @documentView(userForm)
}
```

in `documentView.scala.html`

```
@(userForm: Form[User])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

<H2>Documents Form</H2>
<input type="hidden" name="document.id" value='@userForm("document.id").value' >
@inputText(
   userForm("document.number"), 
   '_label -> "Number: "
)
```

So while saving User you can find id and new number of the document in the request and update the Document with these data:

```
public static result saveUserAndDoc(){
    // save user as usually by binding the form...

    Integer documentId = Integer.valueOf(form().bindFromRequest().get("document.id"));

    Document document = Document.find.byId(documentId);
    document.number = Integer.valueOf(form().bindFromRequest().get("document.number"));
    document.update(documentId);
    return ok("User saved with changed document number);
}
```

of course that sample doesn't contain `<form></form>` tag - just fields - you need to add in proper places that

Comment: I apreciate your help. I have some doubts about the final solution design.In the first approach I don't want to passing it as a new parameter. In a near futuro I'll have objects looks like Document (I'll need to pass a new Form parameter and change an action too) I prefere aboid it.The second proposal is working with a different object model. Some times the Document appears in others classes Customers etc.Now...I would change my views (newUserView.scala.html documentView.scala.html and ) in order to receive Fields not Form[xxx] What do you think about this?